# Lenovo external monitor failing to deliver good quality, blurry fonts instead

Tags: display, font, displayport, resolution

When I connect MacBook Air 11" to the external monitor (Lenovo 24" QHD) via "Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter 1080P", the resolution I get is 1600 x 900 but I expect to get 2560 x 1440 since it is what my friend gets connecting his Macbook Pro  to the exact same monitor. So the quality is not sharp, but blurry. I'd like to know how can I get the specified resolution (2560 x 1440) with that setting (HDMI port), if possible.

[image]

Comment: The Lenovo 24" QHD seems to display DisplayPort directly, you might get better results that way. Also, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @nohillside, I'd like to know how can I get the specified resolution (2560 x 1440)  with that setting (HDMI port), if possible.

Comment: Then please edit the question to include the actual thing you are asking for :-)

Comment: Your MDP > HDMI adapter may not be able to give you this resolution. A listing for the adapter you have [at Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B072PZN5ZK) indicates that it: "Supports resolution up to 1920 by 1080". You may have better luck with the [Belkin 4K MDP > HDMI](https://amazon.com/Belkin-DisplayPort-Adapter-Compatible-Black/dp/B013P0JTX0) adapter: "This Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter allows you to enjoy 4K video (3840 x 2160) at a 30Hz frame rate, which is over four times the pixel count of 1080p."

Comment: Lose the HDMI.   The monitor supports DP directly?  You should **always** opt for that when possible.  Something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Mini-DisplayPort-Black/dp/B00C7RL33M